# Is the reaction stated below a SN1 or SN2 when ethanol is a solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry

According to me, ethanol has an acidic H (attached to O) so it should support SN1 as a protic solvent.
But in case of the following example, it is taken as an aprotic solvent, and thusly the reaction is stated as SN2[image]

Comment: It is not an aprotic solvent. Cyanide anion is a far better nucleophile than EtOH (not ethoxide) so the secondary nitrile is formed by what is probably a mixture of SN1 and SN2

Comment: That is  exactly what I’m asking, whether ethanol is aprotic or protic

Comment: EtOH is a protic solvent